# How can I reload reCaptcha v3?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I saw Google Docs and didn't found information about reloading reCaptcha v3.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

How can I do that?

Comment: Define “reloading”.

Comment: After all form's submissions, I need reload captcha, right? How can I do that?

For example, User submitted the form and saw error "Wrong Captcha". After that, he should fix all errors and try again. And I need reload captcha, right?

Comment: Is reloading the current page Location.reload() not an option?

Comment: No, how can I explain to the user why he should reload the page?

Comment: @igramnet There's no `wrong captcha` or `reload` concept in v3, it's all based on scores calculated automatically. Are you sure about that you do use v3?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Here is the case. The person entered something incorrectly and the captcha wrote a mistake. Now it remains only to reload the page, and this is unacceptable. And how can the customer explain that they need to reload the entire page?

Comment: @igramnet I understand. Then it will be easier to help if you show us how you integrate reCaptcha with your form (possibly sent using ajax).

Answer (score 5):

reCaptcha V3 in an **invisible captcha**, it *automagically* detects user behaviors and rate it, **no need to reload or user's direct interaction** with any UI.

> reCAPTCHA v3 returns a score for each request **without user friction**.
> The score is based on interactions with your site and enables you to
> take an appropriate action for your site.

**reCAPTCHA v2 reset**

```
grecaptcha.reset();
```

**reCAPTCHA v3 reset**

Calling the grecaptcha.execute() function that gets rendered on the page , will reset the value by the looks. ([Google Recaptcha V3 - Widget Id when loading captcha through URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906217/google-recaptcha-v3-widget-id-when-loading-captcha-through-url))

```js
    grecaptcha.execute('[Your recaptcha ID]', {
        action: 'general_form_contact_us'
    }).
    then(function(token) {
        document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha-response-v3-contact_us').value = token;
    });
```

**Note** you will need to adjust all your values accordingly.

You can test it by copying this and pasting in the chrome console. After pressing enter it then changes the value of the hidden field.

Comment: I tried your method but nothing worked. Can you make an example?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are refreshing your token with each subsequent postback or call to Google.

In my case, using **reCAPTCHAv3**, I was saving the token to an ASP.NET HiddenField server control for discovery on the back end. However, this control was not getting updated with the new token on subsequent postbacks because of a mistake in my javascript code (I was only refreshing the token if the HiddenField was not blank, which it wasn't on postbacks). I discovered my error by comparing the JSON results returned by Google and discovering the error code "timeout-or-duplicate" on the second response.

The solution was to clear the HiddenField value in JavaScript before calling Google. Hope this helps someone else having this same issue.

```js
//Need to do this before each call to reCAPTCHA to get fresh token.
function resetReCAPTCHAv3() {
    $('#HiddenFieldreCAPTCHAv3ResponseMP').val('');
}
```